# Roslyn NuGet upgrade makes cshtml compilation extremely slow

Tags: c#, performance, razor, roslyn

Have an ASP.NET 4.8 web app that uses Roslyn compiler, to enable more recent C# features in .cshtml pages code-behind.

Been using Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform v. 1.0.8 for years without any issues.
After upgrade to the latest (3.6.0), every time a .cshtml page opens, it takes **at least a minute**.
Other HTML, AJAX calls, etc. are still fast, so I believe the problem is specific to .cshtml/Razor compilation times.

Downgrading back to 1.0.8 restores the (fast) speed.

Tried upgrading Microsoft.Net.Compilers from 2.4.0 to 3.7.0 (latest) -- no luck.
Tried upgrading Microsoft.AspNet.Razor to 3.2.7 (latest) -- no difference.

The problem manifests with or without the VS debugger, and was confirmed on a different (someone else's) dev. machine.

We have to use 3.6.0 for security reasons (or not use Roslyn at all), and can't simply go back to 1.0.8.
So one solution would be to remove these NuGet packages (and the "<system.codedom><compiler ..." reference from web.config) and downgrade all of the Razor C# back to whatever MVC supports by default (C# 5?)

Is there any way to make it work with Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform 3.6.0?

Comment: Please file a feedback item in Visual Studio by going Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem. This will give you an opportunity to record a performance trace which we can then use to investigate further.

Comment: Can you link to it here?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1229301/roslyn-nuget-upgrade-makes-cshtml-compilation-extr.html